# scala and java arrays

Tags: java, scala

Is there any difference on Scala 2.9.1:

```
Array[String]().getClass
```

and Java 7:

```
String[].class
```

?

If so, how would I emulate the Java 7 result in Scala?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`String[].class` translates to `classOf[Array[String]]` in Scala.

In `Array[String]().getClass`, you are creating a string array then invoking its `getClass` method. (`(new String[0]).getClass()` in Java.)